# Como eu posso verificar se dois valores de duas matrizes estão na mesma posição?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, python-3.x, lógica, senhas

Eu estou tentando criar um mini sistema de login usando python, em que é requisitado um login e uma senha, e se os dois coincidirem, por exemplo: o login está na posição 2 e a senha também está na posição 2, o login é aprovado. O meu problema está em verificar se o login e a senha estão na mesma posição, como eu posso fazer isso? No meu código atual, qualquer senha dá acesso a qualquer login. Eu já tentei colocar `x == y` e não funcionou, e eu também pesquisei sobre, mas só achei conteudo sobre NumPy, dá pra usar essa biblioteca para resolver meu problema? (Eu estou começando a programar agora, me desculpem pelas más práticas, se tiverem qualquer outra dica, eu aceito)

```
username = ['pedro', 'marcos', 'ana', 'michael', 'tomas']
key = ['pedro12', 'markos', 'anaconda', 'jackson', 'toma']

user = str(input("Digite seu username: "))
if user in username:
   for x in username:
    if user == x:
        senha = str(input("Digite sua senha: "))
        for y in key:
            if senha in key:
                if senha == y:
                    print("Olá {}".format(x))
            else:
                print('Acesso negado')
else:
    print("Username não encontrado")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se é isso que quer:

```
username = ['pedro', 'marcos', 'ana', 'michael', 'tomas']
key = ['pedro12', 'markos', 'anaconda', 'jackson', 'toma']

user = str(input("Digite seu username: "))
if user in username:
   for i, x in enumerate(username):
    if user == x:
        print("Usuário na posição "+str(i))
        senha = str(input("Digite sua senha: "))
        if senha in key:
            for j, y in enumerate(key):
                if i == j and senha == y:
                    print("Senha na posição "+str(j))
                    print("Olá {}".format(x))
                    #Quebra o for para não precisar gastar processamento
                    #pesquisando outras senhas.
                    break
                else:
                    print("Senha na posição "+str(j))
                    print('Acesso negado')
                    break
else:
    print("Username não encontrado")
```

O que fiz foi pegar o índice no for para poder comparar e o seu "if senha in key:" estava depois do for, e eu coloquei antes.

Answer (score 2):

Viva, podes simplificar bastante e nem precisas de utilizar for loop, mas ao invés de utilizar dois arrays o que parece estranho validares a posição, utiliza antes um dictionary, com o key é o teu nome e o value é a password.

NOTA: Dá uma vista de olhos na documentação, [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) e [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq). Nota do Fernando. É importante também olhares para a análise de complexidade de algoritmos, [aqui](https://pt.slideshare.net/PabloSilva6/c3-m-analisecomplexidade).

```
nomes = {'pedro':'pedro12', 'marcos': 'markos', 'ana': 'anaconda', 'michael': 'jackson', 'tomas': 'toma'}

def login():
  user = str(input("Digite seu username: "))
  if user in nomes.keys():
      senha = str(input("Digite sua senha: "))
      if senha in nomes[user]:
          print("Olá {}".format(user))
      else:
          print('Acesso negado')
  else:
      print("Username não encontrado")
```

**Ou**

Utilizando a tua fonte de dados e obter pelo index se a password existe nessa posição, mais uma vez sem qualquer for loop.

```
username = ['pedro', 'marcos', 'ana', 'michael', 'tomas']
key = ['pedro12', 'markos', 'anaconda', 'jackson', 'toma']

def login():
  user = str(input("Digite seu username: "))
  if user in username:
      index = username.index(user)
      senha = str(input("Digite sua senha: "))
      if senha in key[index]:
          print("Olá {}".format(user))
      else:
          print('Acesso negado')
  else:
      print("Username não encontrado")
```

Comment: +1 por mostrar com dicionário e ainda apresentar o método `list.index`. Eu só aconselharia acrescentar link para a documentação ([essa](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) ou [essa](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) já ajudariam).